# Can't find application.js with javascript_pack_tag(Webpacker)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have installed Webpacker gem in my Rails app and don't really know how to include *app.js* file into *app/javascript/packs* folder.

I put

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

into my application.html.erb layout and

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery
//= require jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ujs
```

into it.

After all in some view(ex. index.html.erb) I have some jQuery in script tag:

```
<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){...
```

And when I refresh page and look in console I get:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/packs/application-5e96d8f9533313f79af6.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

The question is why `javascript_pack_tag` transforms `application.js` into `application-5e96d8f9533313f79af6.js`(with these numbers) in HTML and from where is that coming?

Also I'm mentioning that I'm transforming my app from Bower to Webpack(within Webpacker gem) and not really sure how to include my Bower components to be used with Webpacker.

Any reference would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Those numbers in pack name are normal, it's file digest, sprockets does this too in production (it's used for cache busting and ensuring correct code on client).

`//= require` directives are for sprockets (aka asset pipeline), in webpacker you should use javascript imports (or use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` in config so that `jQuery` identifier will be loaded automatically upon use).

Also you have to switch to npm dependencies - `yarn add jquery jquery-ui jquery-ujs`

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery'",
        "window.$": "jquery"
    })
  ]
```

and use individual imports (in each file import what is used there like there're no other files, webpack will deal with duplicates):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/theme.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/selectable.css';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/core';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectable'; // and so on
import {} from 'jquery-ujs'
```

Comment: thanks for the extensive answer, but is there any way to import jquery and other stuff from bower_components folder which lives in vendor? I used bower-away to delete bower and it allows Webpacker to read its dependencies and install it with yarn. Or plugins are neccessery to add  for webpacker to work?